# Restoring a postgres database hangs - with no error

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently trying to restore a database from a backup created by pg_dump (which is small ~100mb) from a tar file.

However attempting to restore with
`pg_restore -U postgres -f "example.tar"`

just keeps hanging and never seems to work.

What's the best way to try to diagnose and fix the issue?

Comment: The problem is `-f` is for designating a file you want to restore into as a plain text SQL script form the dump file. Is that what you want to do? If not lose the `-f` and also specify `-d` for the database you want to restore to. More information here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

Comment: thanks I'm just trying to restore from a tar file not into an existing database ie the file should create the database and load in the data

Comment: But as I said above `-f` will restore to the file mentioned not to a database. So you are trying to restore to `example.tar` without including the file you are restoring from, which I'm guessing is `example.tar`. Hence the hanging. Even if the dump file is set up to `CREATE DATABASE` you will need to connect to another database via `-d` for that to happen. It is all spelled out in the link I posted, spend some time there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's waiting for input on stdin.

`-f` specifies an *output file*, not an input file. With no input it's waiting for input on stdin. If you type `ctrl-d` to end input it will say something like `pg_restore: error: input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)`.

The proper invocation is...

```
pg_restore --dbname=DatabaseName -Upostgres --format=tar example.tar
```

`--dbname` is the name of the database to restore to. If it does not exist, add `--create` to tell `pg_restore` to create it.

The `--format=tar` is not strictly necessary, `pg_restore` can guess the file type, but why risk it?

See [the pg_restore docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: This is one of the most confusing pieces of software ever: `pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified`

Comment: Why for some reason you need to specify database name OR output file name, what's the relation between two?

Comment: @Drachenfels From the docs: *pg_restore can operate in two modes. If a database name is specified, pg_restore connects to that database and restores archive contents directly into the database. Otherwise, a script containing the SQL commands necessary to rebuild the database is created and written to a file or standard output. This script output is equivalent to the plain text output format of pg_dump.* `-f` is needed because `pg_dump` usually writes to a non-text format.